# How can I insert json data to server using Volley Android Java?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

With authorization token, And this is the JSON data

{
"fee": 77,
"package": {
"type": "small",
"weight": 3,
"length": 18,
"width": 12,
"height": 5
},
"items": [
{"name":"All", "description":"All", "worth":"1000", "payment":false}
],
"pickup_info": {
"name":"John Wick",
"contact":"09123123123",
"address":"Complete, Address",
"addressSpecific":"Bridge"
},
"delivery_info":  {
"name":"John Wick 2",
"contact":"09321321321",
"address":"Complete, Address 2",
"addressSpecific":"Purok Orange"
}
}

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject Package = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("fee", 77);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Package.put("type", "small");
        Package.put("weight", "3");
        Package.put("length", "18");
        Package.put("width", "12");
        Package.put("height", "5");
        object.put("package", Package);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //items
    JSONObject items = new JSONObject();
    try {
        items.put("name", "All");
        items.put("description", "All");
        items.put("worth", "1000");
        items.put("payment", "false");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(items);
        object.put("items", jsonArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //pickup
    JSONObject pickup_info = new JSONObject();
    try {
        pickup_info.put("name", "sample");
        pickup_info.put("contact", "0912121212");
        pickup_info.put("address", "Complete, Cebu");
        pickup_info.put("addressSpecific", "Bridge");
        object.put("pickup_info", pickup_info);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //delivery
    JSONObject delivery_info = new JSONObject();
    try {
        delivery_info.put("name", "sample 2");
        delivery_info.put("contact", "012121212");
        delivery_info.put("address", "Complete, Cebu 2");
        delivery_info.put("addressSpecific", "Bridge 2");
        object.put("delivery_info", delivery_info);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String URL = "https://www.jogx.ph/api/v1/transaction/createOrder";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            String your_string_json = object.toString() ; // put your json
            return your_string_json.getBytes();
        }


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            headers.put("authToken","token");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? you should add that too

Comment: here sir I edit my post i'm using volley

Answer (score 0):

Try using JsonObjectRequest rather than StringRequest.

Your should change code

```
String URL = "https://www.jogx.ph/api/v1/transaction/createOrder";
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,object,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              Log.e("VOLLEY",error.toString());
   }
}){
    @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            headers.put("authToken","yourToken");
            return headers;
        }
};
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Also you should not share auth token in questions.

Comment: Hi sir it gives me an error message
E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Where is exception occurred? Can you share stack trace?